# Can I set some configuration flag in java whether null == null will be false or true?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, null

Is there any configuration flag exists in java whether null == null will be compared as false or true?

Now it always results to true.

The use case is to align following logic with mysql so it could return the same results:

**In java**

```
System.out.println(null == null); //true
```

**In mysql**

```
select if(null = null, 'true', 'false'); -- false
```

In other words is there a configuration feature in java, which allows configuring the resulting logic of comparisons (f.e. as well as what will be the output of Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY == Double.NaN)?

```
Configuration table

Configuration flag                     | Default  | Set Value
-------------------------------------- | ------   | --------
null==null                             | true     | false
Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY == Double.NaN | false    | false
true = true                            | true     | true   
.....
```

So is it configurable via some flag?

Comment: That option is outright dangerous, because such things are not transparent to code. Everything in Java checks for nullability, now imagine that suddenly this code stopped working: `if (arg == null) { return 0; } else { return arg.hashCode(); }` because someone just "felt like it".

Comment: Is there any programming language that has such a configuration flag?

Comment: @AdamSiemion #define TRUE FALSE ?

Comment: @wings how is it related to `null == null` being true or false?

Comment: @wings was not meant define true as false, as long as it is rarely could be needed, however it can be added to configuration options as well. It could be a configuration table, please find updated question with added table.

Comment: @m-prokhorov no, probably I was not clear enough. Please find updated question with added table.

Comment: @adam-siemion In java[java1.6.0_45] null == null is now being true. In mysql[mysql5.6.28] is now being false. By searching and activating corresponding flag, it would merge the results of functionality.

Answer (score 4):

The result of `null == null` is [defined by the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3):

> At run time, the result of == is true if the operand values are both null or both refer to the same object or array; otherwise, the result is false.

Any configuration option that would redefine this behaviour would violate the specification.